# File.ReadAllLines of two .text files, is this possible to put in one single list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, text

So I have a list with text files, but now I want to .Add 2 .text files into 1 single .Add. Its hard for me to explain, but hopefully you can understand with this example:

```
List.Add(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\glb1.txt" + "C:\\Users\\glb2.txt").ToList());//This isnt possible??
List.Add(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\abc.txt").ToList());
List.Add(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\klm1.txt" + "C:\\Users\\klm2.txt").ToList());//This isnt possible??
```

So is it possible to add 2 text files into one [] of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) + [`List.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines(path1)
       .Concat(File.ReadLines(path2))
       .Concat(File.ReadLines(path3))
       .Concat(File.ReadLines(path4))
       .Concat(File.ReadLines(path5));
List.AddRange( allLines );
```

Comment: Tells me:  `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>'`

Comment: @wouter: should work as expected, i have tested it. `Concat` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and `List<string>.AddRange` expects one. Have you used `AddRange`?

Comment: I fixed it, my List is a 2D list, but i got it working now with Concat thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is.  Use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\glb1.txt"));
List.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\glb2.txt"));
List.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\abc.txt"));
List.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\klm1.txt"))
List.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\klm2.txt"))
```

Use one path at a time. Notice, there's no need to call `ToList` before adding them

Comment: You sure it wont read it like this: `C:\\Users\\glb1.txtC:\\Users\\glb2.txt` ?

Comment: @wouter Why don't you try it and find out, if you're unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Or, even nicer, using LINQ:

```
var files = new []{"glb1.txt", "glb2.txt", "abc.txt", "klm1.txt", "klm2.txt"}; //An array of all the file names you want
var mylist = files.SelectMany(p=>File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users", p))).ToList(); //This list will now hold every line from each of the files
```

`SelectMany` works like `Select`, but it will also flatten the lists into one. So what this does, is that for each filename in `files`, it will read the complete path, and select (return) a list of lines. SelectMany will then combine all the lines into a single list.

If necessary, you can now write `List.AddRange(mylist)` (or, even better, you can replace `var mylist = ...` with `List = ...`).

Also, you should be careful naming your `List` "List", as that may create confusion. To use another name than the type name, such as "myList" instead, is always a good idea.